# Visual Studio 2022 crashes when using breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-2022

When I start my Blazor app (F5) using Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise Version 17.5.2 and previous, my app works. As **soon as I set a breakpoint, the app crashes**. When I remove the breakpoints, the app works again. The problem first occurred occasionally, now permanently. Colleagues have also observed this on their machines. When I create a console application, I can use breakpoints as usual.

I tried without success:

- run \devenv.exe /ResetSettings
- restart the pc
- updatet VS

What could be the cause of this behavior and **how can it be fixed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem for a lot of people since the latest windows security update.

Keep an eye on this for solutions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1189857/blazor-app-crashes-when-debugging-after-windows-se?page=3#answers